# Python Decompose by class BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have problem with remove tag by class its my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

str='<div class="akj-description-header" style="font-size:19px;">Hevesett <span style="color: #020202;font-weight: bold;">+50mm</span> utviklet av <span style="color: #020202;font-weight: bold;">Trailmaster</span>.  <span class="akj-description-price" style="color: #020202;font-weight: bold;">8999 NOK.</span> Særlig tilpasset <span style="color: #020202;font-weight: bold;">Jeep Wrangler TJ 96-06</span>.<br/><br/></div><p></p><p style="font-size:16px;">Trailmaster er Europas ledende produsent av hevesett for terrengbiler. Mens andre produkter er designet for å møte kravene i det amerikanske eller det australske marked, er Trailmasters støtdempere og systemer for hevesett utviklet for å møte kravene i det europeisk markedet. Her er sikkerhets- og kvalitetskravene er høyere. I tillegg er produktene produsert i Europa: Alle delene kommer fra samme sted, passer til sammen og utgjør et helhetlig system.</p><p class="clearfix"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: large;"><strong> </strong></span></p><p class="clearfix"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: large;"></span></p><p> </p><p><span style="font-size: medium;">-The kit included all necessary parts for installation.</span></p><p><span style="font-size: medium;"> </span></p><p align="left"><span style="font-size: large;"><strong>Hevesett inkluderer:</strong></span></p><p><span style="font-size: medium;"> Monteringssett</span></p><p><span style="font-size: medium;"> Installasjons instruksjon</span><br/><span style="font-size: medium;"></span><br/><span style="font-size: large;"><strong> </strong></span></p><p class="clearfix"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: large;"><strong> </strong></span></p>'

def description_filter(description):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(description, "lxml")
    for span in soup.select('.akj-description-price'):
        print(span)
        print(soup)
        span.decompose()
    unwrapElements(soup, "html")
    unwrapElements(soup, "body")
    return soup

def unwrapElements(soup, elementsToFind):
    elements = soup.find_all(elementsToFind)
    for element in elements:
        element.unwrap()


description_filter(str)

print(str)
```

Its find span but not remove from soup...
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually remove span from your soup but you are not changing your `str` value but printing old one.so you didnt recognize it. If you want to change your `str` after some operation just change `description_filter(str)` to

```
str = description_filter(str)
print(str) // will print new str without span class akj-description-price
```